# Regex duration in seconds

Tags: php, regex

I'm sorry, I speak English little.

My PHP code:

```
$duration = "3 h 33 min";
preg_match( '/(?<h>.*) h (?<m>.*) min/', $duration, $time );
$h = $time['h'] * 60 * 60;
$m = $time['m'] * 60;
$s = $h + $m;
```

It works, but my durations:

12 sec

75 sec

2 min

69 min

1 h

2 h 35 min

How to write regex or better idea in PHP? I need the output in seconds.

Comment: Is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004794/3832970) working for you? If not, please explain what is not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the input is always correct and only contains the hours, minutes or seconds values marked with the strings you mentioned, you can use

```php
$text = "2 h 35 min";
$rx = '~(\d+)\h*(h|min|sec)~';
$res = 0;
if (preg_match_all($rx, $text, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER,0)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if ($match[2] === "h") {
            $res += (int)$match[1] * 60 * 60;
        } else if ($match[2] === "min") {
            $res += (int)$match[1] * 60;
        } else if ($match[2] === "sec") {
            $res += (int)$match[1];
        }
    }
}
echo $res;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/QV82d).

The `(\d+)\h*(h|min|sec)` regex matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more digits, `\h*` matches zero or more horizontal whitespaces and then `h`, `min` or `sec` are matched and captured into Group 2.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer does solve the problem. I took an approach similar to yours.

I didn't use named group captures `(?<name>...)` but you could if you preferred. My solution encloses a `(\d+) timeunit` in a non capturing group, `(?:...)`. Meaning it doesn't end up in `$m` matches. Then we make the group optional through `?`. The groups are the separated by  `*` meaning 0 or more white spaces.

```php
$test = [
    '' => 0,
    'invalid duration' => 0,
    '12 sec' => 12,
    '75 sec' => 75,
    '2 min' => 120,
    '69 min' => 69 * 60,
    '1 h' => 60 * 60,
    '2 h 35 min' => 2 * 60 * 60 + 35 * 60,
];

function duration_in_seconds(string $duration): int
{
    preg_match('/(?:(\d+) h)? *(?:(\d+) min)? *(?:(\d+) sec)?/', $duration, $m);

    return ((int) ($m[1] ?? 0)) * 60 ** 2 +
        ((int) ($m[2] ?? 0)) * 60 ** 1 +
        ((int) ($m[3] ?? 0));
}

foreach ($test as $durationString => $duration) {
    echo 'Expected: ', str_pad((string) $duration, 5), '  got: ', duration_in_seconds($durationString), PHP_EOL;
}
```